# I have a question about calculating integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I need some help to solve this integral: 
$$\int_{4x}^{\infty} \frac{w^{\frac{m}{2}}e^{-a\sqrt{w+2\sqrt{xw}}}}{\sqrt{w^2-4xw}}\mathrm{d}w.$$

Thank you

Comment: Try expanding $w^2-4xw=(w-2\sqrt{xw})(w+2\sqrt{xw})$.

Comment: I did this. But I could not see any result.

Comment: Can you post your attempt? Note that $(w^2-4xw) \to 0$ as $w \to 4x$